# Text Overlapping floated images in Chrome/Safari only

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

URL to see this issue: http://www.canadiantraveller.net/816-Viva_Italia_-_Italy_Celebrates_150_Years_Of_Unity

I'm having an issue with some text overlapping onto (and underneath) an image and an Adsense ad.  If you take a look at the page you'll see an image of a bust sculpture, followed directly below it by and adsense block.  They are both floated right with the adsense block having a "clear: right" on it to bump it below the image.  For some reason this "clear: right" is causing the text to overlap the following image (another statue) and flow behind the adsense block.  If I pull out the "clear:right" the text flows fine, with the only problem being that the adsense block and the 1st image (the bust) appear side by side (obviously unwanted).

This works as expected in FF and IE.

**Notes:** 
The ad placement is done by code, placing the ad in the first available position that it will fit in without being disrupting to the article.

The articles are written (via an editor) by someone else and thus changing the css in article is not really feasable.

Ideally I'd like to fix this either in the included CSS file or in the code that inputs the adsense block.  I have complete control over these.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Which Chrome version are you using? I cannot see any issues on Chrome 17.0.942.0 (Windows).